# How to create a new instance with generic type in angular5 service

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to create a new instance with a generic type in angular5 service.
Check out the following codes, please.

```
@Injectable()
export class LookupService {
  duplicate<T>(lookup: T) {
    const temp = new T(lookup);
    return temp;
  }
}
```

But it's not working.
I've been trying to find a solution over a day but can't find it yet.

Thanks

Comment: That's because the constructor of your T class probably doesn't accept an instance of T as the parameters. Show us your T class code.

Comment: I noticed you asked serveral questions but never marked any as answered. If any of the answers solve you problem please remember to mark them as correct with a checkmark

Answer (score 0):

You're close the correct usage:

```
@Injectable()
export class LookupService {
    // You need also a reference to the class to create a new object
    duplicate<T>(lookup: T, clazz: { new(): T }) {
        const temp = new clazz();
        // Set some values of lookup to temp
        return temp;
    }
 }
```

Sample Class

```
export class SampleClass {

    constructor() {
        // Some attributes
    }

}
```

And somewhere in a service or in a component you would call the `duplicate` method like this:

```
const obj: SampleClass = new SampleClass();
// Call the method with the object to clone and its class
this.lookupService.duplicate(obj, SampleClass);
```

If you "don't know" the class of the object you can use a `clone` method of a library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#clone).